# How do I correctly overload methods with two input types `Json::value` and `std:string`?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

I have a `make()` static method in a class `Response`. It is overloaded to take either `std::string` or `Json::Value` from jsoncpp.

I overloaded the method to look like this:

```
Response::make(Json::Value body)
{
  ...
}

Response::make(std::string body)
{
  ...
}
```

This causes this error on compilation:

```
more than one instance of overloaded function "Response::make" matches the argument list:C/C++(308)
main.cpp(15, 20): function "Response::make(std::string body)" (declared at line 28 of "/home/user/weasle/./weasel/./Response.h")
main.cpp(15, 20): function "Response::make(Json::Value body)" (declared at line 36 of "/home/user/weasle/./weasel/./Response.h")
main.cpp(15, 20): argument types are: (const char [33])
```

Is `Json::value` treated as a string? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Let's see how you are calling this function from `main`. -- *How do I correctly overloaded methods* -- The issue probably has nothing to do with this.  It may have everything to do with how you are calling the function.

Comment: Be kind to post a [mcve]. `Response::make(Json::Value body)` is an invalid C++ code.

Comment: The error message indicates that you are trying to call `make` with some string literal as argument. Which of the two overloads _do_ you expect to be used for this? Both can make sense. So maybe overloading isn't the correct approach in this case at all.

Comment: According to documentation (on both sourceforge and github - I'm not sure which is definitive) `Jason::Value` has a constructor that accepts a `const char *`.   So does `std::string`.   Calling `some_response.make("string literal")` will mean that conversions to `std::string` and `Json::Value` are both equally viable, hence the ambiguity.   You need to either remove or rename one of your overloads of `make()`, or force the conversion e.g. `some_response.make(std::string("string literal"))` or `some_response.make(Json::Value("string literal"))` to remove the ambiguity at the call site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the error message, you are passing a `const char[33]` array (I'm assuming a string literal?) to `make()`. But, you don't have an overload that accepts that type, so the compiler has to convert it to another type that you do have an overload for.

However, both `std::string` and `JSON::Value` have a constructor that accepts a `const char*` (which a `const char[]` decays into), so the compiler doesn't know which overload it should call, hence the error.

So, you have 2 choices:

- add a third overload that takes a `const char*` as input:

  ```
  Response::make(const char* body)
  {
    ...
  }

  Response::make(Json::Value body)
  {
    ...
  }

  Response::make(std::string body)
  {
    ...
  }
  ```
- explicitly do the desired conversion yourself at the call site, eg:

  ```
  Response::make(Json::Value("..."));
  ```

  ```
  Response::make(std::string("..."));
  ```

  Alternatively, for `std::string` in C++14 and later:

  ```
  using namespace std::literals;
  Response::make("..."s);
  ```

Comment: Or a less verbose version of the last: `"..."s` if you are using std::literals.